# PHP and C# communication on IIS7 (to generate dynamic PDF)

Tags: c#, .net, php, pdf-generation

Background:

I couldn't find any decent free HTML to PDF conversion utilities in C#. There are 100s of them for PHP with extensive documentation, support, and CSS support. So I am using [html2ps and html2pdf](http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm) (php).

I have PHP 5.2 installed on IIS7 and its working beautifully to create PDFs.

I have the following in `getPDF.aspx`

```
<!-- Output the header -->
<DM:header runat="server" ID="header" />

<asp:Placeholder id="content" runat="server" />

<!-- Output the footer -->
<DM:footer runat="server" ID="footer" />
```

and in `getPDF.aspx.cs`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // AddContentControl simples adds a controls to the content Placeholder.

    AddContentControl("controls/page1.ascx");
    AddContentControl("controls/page2.ascx");
    AddContentControl("controls/page3.ascx");
}
```

and in `generatePDF.php`:

```
<?php
    /* ... includes and stuff here ... */

    $data = "THE HTML GOES HERE!";
    // creates the PDF from the $data and Outputs the created file.
    convert_to_pdf($data);
?>
```

--
getPDF.aspx works perfectly...except the output is HTML.

**So how can I get `getPDF.aspx` to output its HTML as PDF generated by `generatePDF.php`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) a free .NET port of iText (Java-Based PDF Lib) Then you can cut php right out of the equation.

For converting HTML using `iTextSharp` Please See [This Post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1199774.aspx) *(Found using google)*

**Update**

Rendering Partials in ASP.NET Forms (i.e. rendering a single control, or a page with controls) You create a System.Web.Page to drive the event structure.

Here's a code-sample I adapted for a project of mine:

```
    public static string Render<T>(string controlPath, Action<T> initControlCallback) where T : Control
    {
        Page renderPage = new Page();

        // Load the control & add to page
        T control = (T) renderPage.LoadControl(controlPath);
        renderPage.Controls.Add(control);

        // Initialize the control
        initControlCallback.Invoke(control);
        renderPage.DataBind();

        StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(renderPage, result, false); // Render Process
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

It's called like this:

```
MyHelper.Render<MyControlBase>("~/SomePath/SomeControl.ascx", p => { p.SomeProperty = "Initializer" });
```

This code may not be what you need, but as you can see you can render a result using the Server / Page objects, this may be the route you should take.

Comment: I've actually used iTextSharp before...but I didn't know it works with HTML. the string "HTML" is nowhere on their home page.

Comment: I'm working on it now. Now my problem is that I'm trying to render controls and then write their contents into a PDF. The controls rely on their own Page_Load events which don't get fired when using control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter);